# How to remove [] and () from java string

Tags: java, string, replace

I want to remove [, ], ( and ) from my java String.
I have tried `.replaceAll("(", "");` and `.replaceAll("[", "");` but it didn't work. In my program str is read from a file.

```
String str = "I [need] this ]message () without (this[])";
```

Comment: Both "(" and "[" have special meaning in a regular expression. They must be escaped appropriately or else the regular expression will fail to parse and throw an Exception. Also, practice including the *observed behavior*, including the output, instead of a near-useless "it didn't work" statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the `(`, `)`, `[` and `]`. You can do that with `\\`. Something like,

```
String str = "I [need] this ]message () without (this[])";
str = str.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\\(\\)]", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output is

```
I need this message  without this
```

Answer (score 7):

You probably had the solution, but the `replaceAll`method does not modify the string. Save the result in a variable:

```
String str = "I [need] this ]message () without (this[])".replaceAll("[()\\[\\]]", "");
```

The argument `"[()\\[\\]]"` is a regex. The outer `[]` means: one of the inner symbols. These are `(` and `)`. Additionally, you want to match `[` and `]`. But you have to put `\\` before them because they have that special meaning ("one of").

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a double backslash before the [ and the ( in your replaceAll statements:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\(", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").replaceAll("\\)", "");
```

(FYI a single \ will not work as it will evaluate ) as an escaped special character,)